# How to call function to manual hash password?

Tags: symfony

I tried to manually generate new password using:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/password_encoding.html
but I don't understand how to call this function. What should I set as $encoder parameter? Can you provide me some example?

Probably I missed some chapter from doc.

Kind regards,
Lukasz

Comment: Where do you try your code ? In a controller, in a command, in you own php script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $encoder parameter should be the service `security.password_encoder`

You have a documentation here :
http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements#new-service-to-simplify-password-encoding

```
$user = new Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User();
$encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
$password = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $plainTextPassword);
```

Comment: What is "container"? Is some magic black box with useful services?

Comment: It is where services are stored: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html